# Synchronizing the IIS 7 across two app servers

Tags: iis-7

I am using the Shared IIS feature of IIS7 i have taken the config files of one server and put it in a shared location..in the second server i m using these config file from the shared location.I am able to synchronize this but the issue is whenever i m adding a new application in the IIS server of first server the other server doesn't show the latest application...in the second server i am just able to see the Virtual directory and not the application.
Can any1 help me on synchronising the two servers i.e when i add any new application in first server the other server should automatically show the changes.

My business requirement requires runtime generation of the applications in the IIS(which i have completed) the only problem is synchronisation.

Thanks,
Sajesh Nambiar

Answer (score 0):

You need MS WebDeploy to do this implicitly.

http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy